# Ant design <Form.List> create static array of forms

Tags: reactjs, typescript, antd

I am using `antd` with `react` to develop an application.

```
<Form.List name="secondaryContacts">
  {(fields, { add, remove }) => {
    return (
      <div>
        {fields.map((field, index) => (
          <Form.Item
            {...formItemLayoutWithOutLabel}
            label={index === 0 ? "" : ""}
            required={false}
            key={field.key}
          >
            <Form.Item
              {...field}
              validateTrigger={["onChange", "onBlur"]}
              rules={[
                {
                  required: true,
                  validator: phoneNumberValidator
                }
              ]}
            >
              <Input
                placeholder="Secondary Contact"
                addonAfter={
                  fields.length >= 1 ? (
                    <MinusCircleOutlined
                      onClick={() => {
                        remove(field.name);
                      }}
                    />
                  ) : null
                }
              />
            </Form.Item>
          </Form.Item>
        ))}
        <Form.Item {...formItemLayoutWithOutLabel}>
          <Button
            type="dashed"
            onClick={() => {
              add();
            }}
            style={{ width: "100%" }}
          >
            <PlusOutlined /> Add Secondary Contact
          </Button>
        </Form.Item>
      </div>
    );
  }}
</Form.List>;
```

Above is the code I am using to add dynamic form fields with validation using `Form.List`.

Now I have a specific scenario where I need to show 7 Sliders(https://ant.design/components/slider/) for the selected `time slot` and store them in an array, so I thought of using `Form.List` and keep all sliders inside just like above(except that it's static).

But I am not clear **how I can achieve it with `Form.List`** and there are very few examples on the internet.

I have a scenario where I need to have an array of forms and club them as an array using Form.List.

Comment: what difficulty u facing?

Comment: Not able to add a form.list entry for static set of items.

Comment: Have you solved the issue?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `initialValue` property to set the static data

Example:

```
const staticValue = [{ formItem1: 'value1', formItem2: 'value2'}];
    
<Form.List name="formListName" initialValue={staticValue}>
    {(fields, { add, remove }, { errors }) => (
        fields.map((field) => (
            <>
                <Form.Item {...field} name={[field.name, 'formItem1']}>
                    <Input placeholder="Field 1" />
                </Form.Item>
                ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You still need `<Form>` component

Try

```
<Form>
  <Form.List>
  </Form.List>
</Form>
```